# Virtuemart: what happens when final price is higher than base price?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I set below product price in back end,

```
Cost price = Rs. 205  
Base price = Rs. 205 (Apply no rule)  
Final price = Rs. 230 (Apply no rule)  
Override = Rs. 230 (Overwrite price to be taxed)
```

in front end

```
Save Rs. -25  
Final price Rs. 230
```

Actually "Save Rs. -25" should not be displayed in my case. It is VM bug? or wrong in my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bug from the VM ,

Its calculated like.

`Override` Value should be `Base price` - `Override`.

So in your case it will be  205 - 230 = -25

VM already mentioned that Overrde should be discount (means always lesser than `Base price`) They have the tooltip message.

Hope its make sense..

Comment: Thanks for your info. I didnt checked the Override tooltip message. (I didnt have 15 reputation to vote up :))